# Storing multiple username and passwords credential in keychain

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, keychainitemwrapper

I'm creating an application that requires the user to log in, I've read that it's a bad idea to use `NSUserDefaults` so I want to go with either storing the data inside a `sqlite database`or use `keychain` access. My app will show data based on what user is logged in from that device, so if two people have an account with me they can log in from the same device and it shows the data pertaining to their log in. Is it possible to store multiple log in credentials with `keychain` or should I go with an `sqlite` database so that I can properly connect it to the data pertaining to that log in? If `keychain` is the best way can someone point me to a demo that lets you store multiple users in the `keychain`.

```
Update
```

The reason I need to store multiple user/pass in the `keychain` is because after they log in they are required to create a four digit pin to use within the app. As of now if someone else logs in it uses the previous pin instead of asking for the user to create a new one. Should I add an if statement to check if the user is in the `keychain` and if they are not there call the pincontroller. Using the keychain how can I tell which pin belongs to which user?

Comment: Why would you not log 1 user out, delete the details and store the new user login?

Comment: What @Wain is suggesting is the standard way to do it. But either way you would still want to use the keychain.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify I'll add more to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS provides a very secure way to do this via the keychain. It's really the only way to store this type of information so I strongly recommend against rolling your own solution.

If you want to access the keychain you can use one of the many libraries available for this. Here are two:

https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain

https://github.com/secondgear/SGKeychain